# Crear Post en Wordpress con codigo PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

Alguien sabe como crear un post en Wordpress por medio de algun script PHP, necesito crear post semi-automaticos en una web periodicamente, mi idea es crear un codigo php en la misma web con el que por medio de un cron se active cada cierto tiempo y se cree un post claro esta mandandole el titulo contenido featured image y tags si alguien me puede ayudar por favor con algo que me oriente se lo agradeceria mucho

Comment: Puedes hacerlo por correo. Manda los post a alguna cuenta que pueda leer tu WP y ya.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existen varias posibilidades:

**A. USANDO LAS FUNCIONES DE WORDPRESS**

Podrías no sólo crear, sino también actualizar.
Ver:

1. [$post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/$post)
2. [wp_insert_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/)

> Algún o algunos `include`son necesarios

**Código de ejemplo**

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'PostCreator' ) ) {

    function PostCreator(
        $name      = 'AUTO POST',
        $type      = 'post',
        $content   = 'DUMMY CONTENT',
        $category  = array(1,2),
        $template  = NULL,
        $author_id = '1',
        $status    = 'publish'
    ) {

        define( POST_NAME, $name );
        define( POST_TYPE, $type );
        define( POST_CONTENT, $content );
        define( POST_CATEGORY, $category );
        define( POST_TEMPLATE, '' );
        define( POST_AUTH_ID, $author_id );
        define( POST_STATUS, $status );

        if ( $type == 'page' ) {
            $post      = get_page_by_title( POST_NAME, 'OBJECT', $type );
            $post_id   = $post->ID;
            $post_data = get_page( $post_id );
            define( POST_TEMPLATE, $template );
        } else {
            $post      = get_page_by_title( POST_NAME, 'OBJECT', $type );
            $post_id   = $post->ID;
            $post_data = get_post( $post_id );
        }

        function hbt_create_post() {
            $post_data = array(
                'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( POST_NAME ),
                'post_content'  => POST_CONTENT,
                'post_status'   => POST_STATUS,
                'post_type'     => POST_TYPE,
                'post_author'   => POST_AUTH_ID,
                'post_category' => POST_CATEGORY,
                'page_template' => POST_TEMPLATE
            );
            wp_insert_post( $post_data, $error_obj );
        }

        if ( ! isset( $post ) ) {
            add_action( 'admin_init', 'hbt_create_post' );
            return $error_obj;
        }

    }
}

/* All available options for PostCreator()

PostCreator( 'TITLE' , 'POST TYPE' , 'POST CONTENT' , 'POST CATEGORY' , 'TEMPLATE FILE NAME' , 'AUTHOR ID NUMBER' , 'POST STATUS');

TITLE - HTML Stripped Out. Simple String.
POST TYPE - Post type slug. Eg 'post' or 'page'. Custom Post Types are supported.
POST CONTENT - Content of the Post/Page. HTML allowed.
POST CATEGORY - An array of the integer ID's of the category/categories you want to link to your post
TEMPLATE FILE NAME - File name of the template. Only for Pages. In the format 'file_name.php'.
AUTHOR ID NUMBER - Integer value. Default is 1.
POST STATUS - Available options; [ 'draft' | 'publish' | 'pending'| 'future' | 'private' | custom registered status ]

If successful, PostCreator() returns nothing.
If there is an error PostCreator() returns a WP_error object.

*/

PostCreator( 'My Lorem Ipsum', 'page', 'With a sizable serving of Dolor. This was created using Harri Bell-Thomas\'s PostCreator function.' );
```

[Fuente de este código](http://www.wpexplorer.com/create-wordpress-posts-pages-using-php/)

---

**B. USANDO LA (CUESTIONADA) [API XML-RPC](https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Posts#wp.newPost)**

En WordPress, el protocolo XMLRPC es una especie de interfaz que actúa como API para aplicaciones externas y que nos permite interactuar con una instalación de WordPress utilizando aplicaciones o servicios externos.
Al funcionar como una interfaz externa es casi como una “puerta de entrada” la cual puede ser en consecuencia **atacada fácilmente desde el exterior** causando un alto consumo de recursos al ejecutarse una y otra vez el proceso de autentificación.

En muchos sitios esta API es puesta en cuestión y cuando no se usa es aconsejable desactivarla  ([ver por ejemplo](https://raiolanetworks.es/blog/xmlrpc-php-de-wordpress-que-es-y-como-protegerlo/)).

De todos modos, aquí tienes un ejemplo:

```
function wpPostXMLRPC($title,$body,$rpcurl,$username,$password,$category,$keywords='',$encoding='UTF-8') {
    $title = htmlentities($title,ENT_NOQUOTES,$encoding);
    $keywords = htmlentities($keywords,ENT_NOQUOTES,$encoding);

    $content = array(
        'title'=>$title,
        'description'=>$body,
        'mt_allow_comments'=>0,  // 1 to allow comments
        'mt_allow_pings'=>0,  // 1 to allow trackbacks
        'post_type'=>'post',
        'mt_keywords'=>$keywords,
        'categories'=>array($category)
    );
    $params = array(0,$username,$password,$content,true);
    $request = xmlrpc_encode_request('metaWeblog.newPost',$params);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $rpcurl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
    $results = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $results;
?>
```

[Fuente de este código](http://www.wprecipes.com/post-on-your-wordpress-blog-using-php/)

---

**C. INSERTANDO EN LA BASE DE DATOS MYSQL**

Las entradas de WP son almacenadas en una [Base de Datos MySQL](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description). No será difícil crear un script que se conecte a la BD y cree un post insertando los datos que envíes en la/las tablas correspondientes.

Comment: Gracias lo logre usando las funciones de Wordpress pero hay que añadir este include: require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php');

Comment: Muy bueno, se dejó adaptar perfectamente a lo que quería.